# no matching function for call error on class constructor

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm getting the following error stating there's no matching function call:

```
no matching function for call to 'Chord::Chord(const char [5], Note* [3], int, int)'
```

I'm fairly new to C++ so I could be making an elementary mistake. But what I am trying to do is put notes on the heap, pass them to a constructor and have those notes copied to a private property within the `Chord` class.

I can't seem to pinpoint why this is happening.

Inside **main** ...

```
Note *notes[] = {
    new Note(0, "C", "B#"),
    new Note(5, "E", "Fb"),
    new Note(8, "G", "G")
};

Chord chord = new Chord("CMaj", notes, 127, 1);
```

**Chord.h**

```
/*
 * Chord.h - Library for generating and playing chords
 * Created by James Jeffery <jameslovescode@gmail.com>, March 11, 2017.
 */
#ifndef Chord_h
#define Chord_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Note.h"

class Chord
{
  public:
    Chord(String chord_name, Note notes[], int octave, int velocity);
    String getChordName();
    void play();
    void stop();
  private:
    Note notes[];
    String chord_name;
    int octave;
    int velocity;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Ahhh. I thought it would be a simple issue. Please put as answer and I will accept.

Comment: My original suggestion was actually wrong, I tried to explain it a bit in my answer - comment there if anything is unclear

Comment: It looks like you're a recovering Java programmer. C++ programmers avoid the word `new` as much as possible. (And the `Note notes[];` member isn't valid C++.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Good guess, you're right. Do you have any resources that can explain this more and alternative programming practices to avoid using new all over the place?

Comment: Nevermind, found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new

Comment: @BugHunterUK [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is declared to accept an array of `Note`, but `Note *notes[]` declares an array of `Note*`. As you stated in your question that you want to allocate the `Note`s on the heap you should adjust your class to take `Note *notes[]` in the constructor and store an array of pointers in its member.

However this solution can (and quite likely will) have issues with ownership and deallocation (who is in charge of `delete`ing the allocated objects and when does it happen? And how to prevent any dangling pointer in that case?).

The IMO better approach would be to store the `Note`s in automatic duration inside the `Chord` class, so that they will be destroyed when the "owner" object gets destroyed. For this all you'd need to change would be the initial array you want to pass to:

```
Note notes[] = {
    Note(0, "C", "B#"),
    Note(5, "E", "Fb"),
    Note(8, "G", "G")
};
```

Another option (if you really want to have the `Note`s be dynamically allocated) could be the have your `Chord` constructor create copies of the `Note`s passed as a parameter, which could be allocated with `new` and destroyed in the destructor of `Chord` - this would solve the issues mentioned in the first solution (but it would disconnect the `Note`s in `Chord` from the ones passed in via the constructor)

Note: you also have another minor syntax error in your question: `Chord chord = new Chord("CMaj", notes, 127, 1);` should be `Chord* chord = new Chord("CMaj", notes, 127, 1);`